# How can I create a conditional statement to dynamically create a unique button for each ID?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, dynamic, conditional-statements

This is a form where people have to input their names and the button I'm creating is for team members to select their available times.

```
    let button = document.createElement("Button");
    let buttonTxt = document.createTextNode("Select Times");
    button.appendChild(buttonTxt);

    function createButton(){
      
        let name1 = document.getElementById("name1"); 
        let name2 = document.getElementById("name2");
        let name3 = document.getElementById("name3");
        let name4 = document.getElementById("name4");
        let name5 = document.getElementById("name5");

        if (name1 && name1.value) { // if there is a name in the input, a button will be created for their section
            document.getElementById('b1').appendChild(button);
        } 
        if (name2 && name2.value) {
            document.getElementById('b2').appendChild(button);
        } 
        if (name3 && name3.value) {
            document.getElementById('b3').appendChild(button);
        } 
        if (name4 && name4.value) {
            document.getElementById('b4').appendChild(button);
        } 
        if (name5 && name5.value) {
            document.getElementById('b5').appendChild(button);
        } }
```

If statements work individually but when put in a function it doesn't work anymore. Below is the HTML where top is the code from the form while the bottom HTML is from where the button should be created. The buttons will need to be ab;e to add event properties on them (ex. onclick)

```
        <h4>Team Host:</h4>
        <p><input type="text" name="name1" value="Enter Name" id="name1"> 
        </p>
        <br>
        <h4>Other Members:</h4>
        <p><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"></p> 
        <br>
        <p><input class='new' type='text' name='name3' id='name3'></p>
        <br>
        <p><input class='new' type='text' name='name4' id='name4'></p>
        <br>
        <p><input class='new' type='text' name='name5' id='name5'></p>

        <p id="p1"></p>
        <p>Times go here</p>
        <p id="b1" name="b1"></p>
        <p id="p2"></p>
        <p>Times go here</p>
        <p id="b2" name="b2"></p>
        <p id="p3"></p>
        <p>Times go here</p>
        <p id="b3" name="b3"></p>
        <p id="p4"></p>
        <p>Times go here</p>
        <p id="b4" name="b4"></p>
        <p id="p5"></p>
        <p>Times go here</p>
        <p id="b5" name="b5"></p>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. But it sounds like you should be using a loop over an array, not a bunch of separate variables.

Comment: You need to clone your button

Comment: Within the paragraph I am appending a button @MisterJojo I edited my question, hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: No name1-5 are inputs and b1-5 are empty paragraphs @MisterJojo

Comment: I added the HTML @MisterJojo

Comment: I have another function where the inputted names are placed where p1-5 are.

Comment: yea forgot to take that out...do you have an idea of how I can dynamically add buttons when there is an input tho using if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this?

```js
const button    = document.createElement('button')
  ,   buttonTxt = document.createTextNode('Select Times')
  ;
button.setAttribute('onclick', 'foo(this)')  // add click function to button
 
button.appendChild(buttonTxt);

document.querySelectorAll('#name1,#name2,#name3,#name4,#name5')
        .forEach(nm=>
          {
          if(nm.value) 
            {
            let newBt = button.cloneNode(true)
              , ref   = nm.id.replace(/^\D+/g,'') 
              ;
            newBt.dataset.info = ref
            document.getElementById(`b${ref}`) // get correspondig B1-5
                      .appendChild(newBt)   // add new button 
            }
          })

// buttons calls
function foo(bt)
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log('clicked is : ', bt.dataset.info )
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
p {
  display          : block;
  height           : 2.4em;
  background-color : lightgrey;
  padding          : .2em;
  margin           : .1em;
  }
 h4 {
  margin : .5em;
 }
```

```html
<h4>Team Host:</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="Enter Name"></p> 
  <br>
<h4>Other Members:</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"></p> 
<p><input type='text' name='name3' id='name3'></p>
<p><input type='text' name='name4' id='name4' value="abc"></p>
<p><input type='text' name='name5' id='name5'></p>
<hr>

<p id="b1"></p>
<p id="b2"></p>
<p id="b3"></p>
<p id="b4"></p>
<p id="b5"></p>
```

Comment: The code works! But could you explain this piece of code: if(nm.value) 
            document.getElementById(`b${nm.id.replace(/^\D+/g,'')}`) @MisterJoJo

Comment: It's a simple regular expression to keep only numeric characters from a string ( and eliminate others characters.  "name1' is changed to "1" to complete the string "b"  ${} is the operation container)

Comment: Ah thank you! I was planning to run a button.onclick = function() on the buttons, but it doesn't work anymore. Do you know why?

Comment: It no longer outputs a button for each name @Mister Jojo

Comment: @kluu2021 this is normal the append method is moving an object to a new location. this was never creating a copy of an object

Comment: Sorry @Mister Jojo I am new to Stackoveflow and am just learning the ropes. I will update the question but the appended buttons when clicked would essentially allow that specifc member to select times from a scheduler I created

Comment: I validated your answer and updated the question and added to the details.  I appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224949/discussion-between-kluu2021-and-mister-jojo).

Comment: @kluu2021 see the new version with data info